# group by and count from another table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following tables:

s2s_actions

```
    id  app_id  brand_id  country_id
------  ------  --------  ----------
    22      15       361           5
    29      15       361           5
    35      15         7          64
    40      15         7          64
    41      15        37           5
    44      15       361           5
```

clicks

```
    id  app_id  country_id  brand_id 
------  ------  ----------  -------- 
   103      15           5       361 
   104      15          64         7 
   105      15           5        37 
   106      15           5        37
```

Is it possible to have a query that groups s2s_actions by brand_id,country_id,app_id and counts the number of clicks for each group?

in that case, results should be:

```
app_id  country_id  brand_id  total_clicks
------  ----------  --------  ------------
    15           5       361             1
    15          64         7             1
    15           5        37             2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an option using `inner join` :

```
select s.app_id, s.country_id, s.brand_id, count(*) as total_clicks
from (
  select distinct s.app_id, s.country_id, s.brand_id, c.id
  from s2s_actions s
  inner join clicks c on c.app_id = s.app_id and c.country_id = s.country_id and c.brand_id = s.brand_id
) as s
group by s.app_id, s.country_id, s.brand_id;
```

Results :

```
app_id  country_id  brand_id    total_clicks
15      5           361         1
15      64          7           1
15      5           37          2
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/U0aHKAz1)

Comment: That worked great! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear :)